# AWS container insights not showing performace metrics

Tags: amazon-eks, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have followed below articles and setup container insights and fluentd for my EKS cluster in AWS. I can see the

1.Setup cloud watch agent demonset in EKS

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Container-Insights-setup-metrics.html

2. Setup  Fluent Bit demonset in EKS

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Container-Insights-setup-EKS-quickstart.html

I can see log groups created for :

```
/aws/containerinsights/EKS-CLUSTER-NAME/application
/aws/containerinsights/EKS-CLUSTER-NAME/dataplane
/aws/containerinsights/EKS-CLUSTER-NAME/host
/aws/containerinsights/EKS-CLUSTER-NAME/performance
```

But When I select Container Insights in cloudwatch it doesn't show the Performace metrics nor map/resources. Any idea why?

```
NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/cloudwatch-agent-98mht   1/1     Running   0          86m
pod/fluent-bit-gq6sk         1/1     Running   0          66m

NAME                              DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR   AGE
daemonset.apps/cloudwatch-agent   1         1         1       1            1           <none>          86m
daemonset.apps/fluent-bit         1         1         1       1            1           <none>          66m
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you have to put the cluster name and region name in the configuration, but it would not have been created because it did not match what you made.

You should check with "kubectl logs [podname]", but that's usually the case.